Allow privileged port mapping not working in Mac Docker-Desktop
I am not able to enable privileged port mapping on MAC Docker Desktop, I have clicked the 'Allow privileged port mapping (requires password)' check box under the advance tab in settings
I am using an Intel-based Mac. I reinstalled Docker-Desktop and rebooted the laptop, but I still have the same issue.
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:389 -> 0.0.0.0:0: failed to connect to /var/run/com.docker.vmnetd.sock: is vmnetd running?: dial unix /var/run/com.docker.vmnetd.sock: connect: no such file or directory

I tried to check if the vmnetd running
 % ps -ef | grep vmnetd
  501 16466  4073   0 11:46PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep vmnetd

Docker Desktop version: v4.34.3
% docker --version
Docker version 27.2.0, build 3ab4256

